# Custom ValidationAttribute error not showing up in ValidationSummary (MVC 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a simple field that I want to ensure is greater than a certain number. Things to note:

1. I can't install any additional NuGet packages.
2. I want to do **server-side** validation.
3. I want to use the following custom validation technique rather than opting for a pre-existing solution, because eventually my validation needs will be far more complex and application-specific.

Here's what's happening:

1. Enter -5 in the Hours text box and click Submit.
2. GreaterThan's IsValid function is called.
3. The `return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));` line is hit (confirmed by tracing through with the debugger).
4. The form posts successfully, and no errors appear in the ValidationSummary area in the view.

I would expect "must be greater than" error to appear after calling ValidationSummary in the view, given that the GreaterThan class determined that -5 is not greater than zero. Any idea why this is not the case?

Here's my custom validation class:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [GreaterThan(0)]
    [DisplayName("Hours")]
    public string Hours { get; set; }
}

public class GreaterThan : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly float _lowerBound;

    public GreaterThan(int lowerBound) : base("{0} must be greater than " + lowerBound + ".")
    {
        _lowerBound = lowerBound;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            float result;
            if (float.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result) && result > _lowerBound)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

The View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Hours)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Hours)

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And the Action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // [...] Some irrelevant stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
    }

    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // [...] Handle the exception
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the MyAction method too please?

Comment: In your action you don't seem to check if the `ModelState.IsValid`. What is that "irrelevant stuff" you have in controller?

Comment: Also "I can't install any additional NuGet packages." smells bad :-( Where is this restriction coming from?

Comment: Ah, it is because I'm not checking for ModelState.IsValid. I had that before, but I had a ModelState.Clear() call in the Index action that shouldn't have been hit on this particular code path. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

why it is of the type string? you could have saved a lot of work if you have used decimal or int. There is an inbuilt range validation.

The Code for range validation

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "0", "99999", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be between {1} to {2}")]
[Required]
[DisplayName("Hours")]
public decimal Hours { get; set; }
```